# Devise - Trying to display the user who made a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, model, devise, controller

I'm creating this rails app,
In the app I have the functionality to make an account, then post a status.
I have made it so I can display the status on the screen, but how do i display the name of the person who made the post? I am using devise and have setup :username

My View

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <h1 id="welcome" class="nuvo">Welcome <%= current_user.username %>!</h1>
<% else %>
  <h1 id="welcome" class="nuvo">Log-In to make some posts!</h1>
<% end%>

<div class="follow-row">
  <div class="titan-users nuvo"><h2>TITAN Users</h2></div>
</div>

<div class="statuses">
  <% if user_signed_in? %><div class="status-form"><%= render 'form' %></div><% end %>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post">
      <div class="tstamp"><strong>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago by <%= current_user.username %></strong></div>
      <div class="status"><%= post.status %></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My Post Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  # GET /posts/new.json
  def new
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

My user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username

  has_many :post
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

My Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status, :author

  belongs_to :user

  validates :status, :presence => true
end
```

So, does anyone have any ideas how in the view instead displaying, 'current_user.username' can I display the name of the person who posted it?

So, for CodeIt this is the error I get

```
undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #17):

14:   <% if user_signed_in? %><div class="status-form"><%= render 'form' %></div><% end %>
15:   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
16:     <div class="post">
17:       <div class="tstamp"><strong>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago by <%= post.user.username %></strong></div>
18:       <div class="status"><%= post.status %></div>
19:     </div>
20:   <% end %>
20:   <% end %>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `post` belongs_to `user`. So you can use:

```
 post.user.username  #In your @posts loop
```

Comment: tried that, just says `undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Have you assigned a user to the post?

Comment: @coreypizzle Its because when you are creating post u need to assign user that post.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm really new to Rails, so what do you mean by assigned?

Comment: Yeh, I only set it so you can see the post form if they are logged in.

Comment: Then change `@post = Post.new` to `@post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])` in `create` method of `PostsController`

Comment: Just did that but still says,`undefined method username' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #17):

14:   <% if user_signed_in? %><div class="status-form"><%= render 'form' %></div><% end %>
15:   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
16:     <div class="post">
17:       <div class="tstamp"><strong>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago by <%= post.user.username %></strong></div>
18:       <div class="status"><%= post.status %></div>
19:     </div>
20:   <% end %>`

Comment: can you just open you rails console?

Comment: kk just opened it! thanks for going to the bother of doing this!

Comment: now do `u=User.first`.. then `u.posts.build`.. check `user_id` is it populated?

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method `posts' for #<User:0x46b6c78>` when i ran u.posts.build

Comment: ohh you have wrong statement in user model. `has_many :post` change to `has_many :posts`. Then reload the console.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: user_id` Is that what your looking for?

Comment: You don't have `user_id` column in posts table?? Can you paste `Post.column_names` ? or check `user_id` is there or not?

Comment: class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.text :status

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: i think thats what you wanted?

Comment: Not migration do `Post.column_names` in console. It will give what column u have in posts table.

Comment: when you have `has_many :posts` relation for `user` you need to have `user_id` in posts model. So create new migration by running command on terminal `$ rails g migration add_user_id_to_posts user_id:integer` then run `rake db:migrate`. This will create `user_id`  for `posts`. Then reload rails console and do `Post.column_names`

Comment: `SQLite3::SQLException: table "posts" already exists: CREATE TABLE "posts"` When i run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: what migration you created ?? Do `$ rails g migration add_user_id_to_posts user_id:integer` ... `migration` not `model`

Comment: rails g migration add_user_id_to_posts user_id:integer

Comment: is it created `user_id` column for posts?? did you run `rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: i ran `rake db:migrate` thats whenever it gave me the `table "posts" already exists`

Comment: sry my email is messing up right now, accidentally changed IMAP filters and POP3 stuff, so sry cant! Could u create some fake questions and then ill answer them and you upvote them?

Answer (score 0):

In your create method in the controller, i dont see you pass the user_id to it,so probably the user dint set into the post model.

Maybe you can put a hidden_field_tag in your form, and pass your user_id as a param.
Then, in your controller,do something like 
@post.user_id = params[:user_id]

Then,in your view,you can access the user_id and find the username from the user_id